# synonym api Ajax call return

Tags: ajax, call, return

Have struggled with this call for a while now but i can't get it to work. dataToReturn still returns Error and not the called data. What am i doing wrong?

```
function get_translation(search) {
    search = search.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "").toLowerCase();
    original = search;
    google.language.translate( original ,  'en', 'sv', 
    function(result) {
        translated = result.translation;
        $("#results").html('<li class="ui-li-has-icon ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c" role="option" tabindex="0">'+ translated + '</li>')   
    });
};

function get_synonyms(items) { 



var dataToReturn = "Error";  

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/1/xxx/' + items+ '/json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

       dataToReturn = data;
    }
});


return dataToReturn;

}


$('#results').delegate("li", "tap", function(){
    myDate = new Date();
    displayDate = myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + myDate.getFullYear();
    id = myDate.getTime();

    var wordObject = {'id' : id, 'date': displayDate, 'translated': translated, 'original': original, 'nmbr': "0", 'syn': get_synonyms('hello')};
    save_terms(wordObject);
    loopItems() ;
    $("#results").html("");
    $("#addField").val("");
    // location.reload(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `return dataToReturn` line is being executed before the AJAX call is complete. When you call `$.ajax`, the browser says, "Okay, I'll just move on to the next thing while I'm waiting for that to get back to me."

The simplest way to fix this would be to change the `success` function to actually do whatever it is you're trying to do with `dataToReturn`. But if that's not really feasible, then more context would help come up with a better answer.

Comment: I thought that async prevented that "move on thing" from happening?

Comment: @Mattias What happens when you get rid of the return and just `alert(dataToReturn)` in the success function?

Comment: then i get the string. But i have to return it. I'm trying this 

var wordObject = {'words' : get_synonyms(var)};

Comment: @Mattias Well, I was just plumb wrong. When I actually tried your code, it worked fine. Again, more context is probably necessary.

Comment: @Mattias Perhaps the problem is with `dataType: 'jsonp'`? What happens if you change that to just `json`?

Comment: yeah, I've tried that to. But if i change it to json, i will retrieve a blank response. I can request is being made and transferred through firebug net but in the consolo log i get the call with a blank response.